# Написать работающий запрос select многие-ко многим на SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, многие-ко-многим

Уважаемые разработчики, прошу помочь с написанием запроса на SQL,так как только  учусь.

Есть таблицы Customer-клиенты,Items-товары с ценами и промежуточная  таблица с заказами-Orders, которая включает количество заказанного. Схема с таблицами внизу. Требуется вывести запросом покупателей и их расходы(Количество*Цена товара).Я написал примерный код, но проверить его не могу, из-за отсутствия на рабочем компьютере SQL Server или других СУБД(в Access join не поддерживается):

```
SELECT Customer.customer_name, Orders.quantity, items.item_price,
    [Quantity]*[item_price] AS [Sum]
FROM (Customer JOIN Orders ON Customer.customer_id = Orders.customer_id)
JOIN items ON Orders.item_id = items.item_id;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад правильному ответу.

Comment: [Здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com) можно все проверить и даже перепроверить

Comment: *проверить его не могу, из-за отсутствия на рабочем компьютере SQL Server или других СУБД* https://dbfiddle.uk/ https://www.db-fiddle.com/ https://sqliteonline.com/ https://sqlize.online/ и прочие. *в Access join не поддерживается* Это кто Вам такую [censored] сказал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не сгруппировали по покупателю:

```
select c.customer_name, sum(o.quantity*i.item_price) Customer_Expenses
from Customer c 
join Orders o on o.customer_id=c.customer_id
join items i on i.item_id=o.item_id
group by c.customer_name
```